# How do I find out that a link was seen

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a page with some links and when somebody clicks on a link, the score count will go up.

How can I find out the visitor who has `really seen` the page related to link? But not just click the link and close the page for score...

really seen means: page loads completed.

and my links opens in new window.

any solution?

Comment: No. You can't control what happens on the other website unless it is yours.

Comment: ... or you are facebook and the other page uses your api ;)

Comment: why you guys vote question down? I dont want to control other websites. I want some thing like iframe onload()

Answer (score 2):

You cant really see pages that aren't in the same domain. Chrome even puts them in a separate thread.

Back in the day you could have used a CSS exploit talked about here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector

If you really want to make a page with this kind of functionality you will have to make a browser plugin/extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can include a nonce token in the link, and post that token to the server, render the page embedding that same token in some javascript and have the javascript post back the token when the page is done rendering. Seems kinda overkill though.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could thing of is maybe make the link to like a redirect page on your site and then you could control to see if the page was loaded and then like after the page was loaded redirect to the actual webpage to link is intended. This way you know for sure that the user waited to view the webpage.

Other than that I don't think there is any other way for you to go about this.